# World wrapping and chase angles

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to make one turtle chase a small group of other turtles, and the turtles being chased turn away from the pursuer at this angle:

```
atan (xcor - [xcor] of pursuer) (ycor - [ycor] of pursuer)
```

When the world is wrapped, subtracting coordinates obviously fails to work, so I was wondering if anyone had encountered this problem before or could figure out a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the reporter towards as it takes world topology into account: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#towards

For instance, if you'd like to move directly away from a target, you would do something along the lines of:

```
ask hunted [ set heading (towards hunter - 180) ]
```